# Eclipse warning in EL (not empty)

Tags: eclipse, jsf, warnings, el, facelets

I use this `rendered="#{not empty facesContext.messageList}"` to render a form. All works fine but my eclipse marker says the following warnings:

Warning1:This empty expression always evaluates to false.  Only string, maps, arrays and collection have meaningful values for the empty operator.

Warning2: This not will always result a value of true.

I use Eclipse Kepler for it. Can i ignore this?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736641/jsf-using-el-to-test-global-messages-presence?

Comment: Yes, its the same solution as mine. And my solution works fine :D only the warning confuse me ;)