# Conditionally render component on presence of message from specific object

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, jsf-2.2

I intend to verify a field `usernameTxt` in form with **bootstrap** below, with a reference to [**BalusC** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18836757/5668956) and [**Aleksei Loginov** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31738371/5668956)

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="usernameTxt">Fullname(*):</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <h:inputText type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameTxt"
                        a:placeholder="Enter your name" required="true"
                        requiredMessage="Fullname is required"
                        value="#{data.personalInformation.username}"></h:inputText>
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList('usernameTxt')}" class="alert alert-danger">
                        <h:message for="usernameTxt"></h:message>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The wish is that if the input text is empty then it will render the block `<h:panelGroup>`, and the result should be like 
[image]

(That photo is when I remove the `not` condition in the `rendered` property). I can't make the block rendered conditionally correctly. Is there any syntax in the render condition, or am I missing something here ?

Comment: Please also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved.

It takes me a whole day to find out that the actual `usernameTxt` id on page has been rendered and it's not like what I expected

[image]

So I have to change the condition back to

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block"
                        rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList('form:j_id_9:useridTxt')}"
                        class="alert alert-danger">
                        <h:message for="useridTxt"></h:message>
                    </h:panelGroup>
```

and it solved my problem